# Delete first node in a LinkedListNode

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I thought I had this program working but unfortunately I've overlooked something. How do you delete the first Node and convert the second node into the front of the Linked List. I've tries a multitude of approaches but end up with the same result.(LinkedList remaining unchanged) Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Node Class

```
public class Node {

    private String data;
    private Node next;

    Node(String data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setData(String d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        next = n;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node list = new Node("NODE 1",new Node("NODE 2",new Node("NODE 3", null)));
        list = insertSecond(list,"New Node");
        list = addLast(list,"LAST NODE");

        printList(list);
        System.out.println();
        deleteNode(list, "NODE 1");
        printList(list);
    }

    public static Node deleteNode(Node list,String str)
    {
        Node temp = list;
        Node prev = list;

        while(temp != null)
        {
            if(temp.getData().equals(str))
            {
                if(temp.getData().equals(list.getData()))
                    {
                    list = list.getNext();
                    return deleteNode(list,str);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        prev.setNext(prev.getNext().getNext());
                    }
            }
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.getNext();

        }

        return list;
```

Comment: Although this is technically a list of nodes, you're better off having a `NodeList` class that keeps a reference to the head and tail of the list. Then you can just point the head reference to the `head.next` element

Comment: I answered this question in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792682/delete-last-node-of-a-linked-list/15793207#15793207

Comment: Dwb you did, and your explanation was clear in the theory behind it but I can not wrap my head around the appropriate syntax to delete the first node and make the the next node the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `deleteNode` function should return the head of new list. This is required only in one edge case which you described - deleting head of that list.

```
list = deleteNode(list, str);
```

Also you don't need to recursively execute `deleteNode` method, iteration over node elements should be enough:

```
public static Node deleteNode(Node list, String str) {
    // I'm assuming that you are deleting the first inscance of the string
    Node temp = list;
    Node prev = list;

    while(temp != null) {
        if(temp.getData().equals(str)) {
            if(temp.getData().equals(list.getData())) {
                return list.getNext();
            }
            else {
                prev.setNext(temp.getNext());
                return list;
            }
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: you are right I missed the return type but it still does not have an effect.

Comment: yes, you're right. I was trying to say that your implementation isn't handling that edge case properly.

Comment: does this approach not return list at position[n] without actually deleting it?

Comment: Nope (; it's returning head of list. In case of deleting first node second one is returned, in any other case we are joining nodes omitting that one which should be removed and returning head of list.