# How to manually implement a Linked List in Java without using a Constructor?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I realize that there are a few good threads already existing which discuss how to implement a linked list in Java, however I can't seem to find one which does not use a constructor like this,

```
public LinkList() {
    Link = null;
}
```

or something along these lines. However, I have not done this in my code, and therefore I am having trouble with writing a few of the methods.

I have a class called Link which contains the following code, note without any constructor like the one displayed above:

```
public class Link {
private Link next = null;
private String value = null;

public Link getNext(){
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Link nextLink){
    next = nextLink;
}

public String getValue(){
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String aValue){
    value = aValue;
}
}
```

and then I have my `LinkedList` class, which contains the following code:

```
public class LinkedList {
private Link head = null;
private Link tail = null;

public Link getHead(){
    return head;
}

public void setHead(Link aLink){
    head = aLink;
}

public Link getTail(){
    return tail;
}

public void setTail(Link aLink){
    tail = aLink;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return(head == null && tail == null);
}

public void addLast(String aString){
    Link link = new Link();
    link.setValue(aString);
    //tail.setNext(link);
    if(isEmpty()){
        head = link;
    }else{
        tail.setNext(link);
    }
    tail = link;

    }

public void addFirst(String aString) {
    Link link = new Link();
    link.setValue(aString);

    if(isEmpty()){  
        tail = link;
    }else{
        head.setNext(link);
    }
    head = link;        
}

public Link removeFirst(){
    Link temp = head;
    head = temp.getNext();
    temp.setNext(null);

    return temp;
}
```

}

My `addFirst` Method, and my `isEmpty` Method both seem to be working but my `addLast` and `removeFirst` Methods are not. I have drawn pictures, looked at pseudo code, and searched around the internet, but I just cannot seem to figure this out.

I need to know how to get my `addLast` and `removeFirst` methods working without having to add in the constructor at the beginning like all the rest of the example code I keep seeing.

Here are the Tests they need to pass:

```
    @Test
public void testRemoveFirst(){
    list.addFirst("three");
    list.addFirst("two");
    list.addFirst("one");
    assertTrue("one".equals(list.removeFirst()));
    assertTrue("two".equals(list.removeFirst()));
    assertTrue("three".equals(list.removeFirst()));
}

@Test
public void testAddLast(){
    list.addFirst("three");
    list.addFirst("two");
    list.addFirst("one");
    assertTrue( "three".equals(list.removeLast()));
    assertTrue( "two".equals(list.removeLast()));
    assertTrue( "one".equals(list.removeLast()));
    assertNull(list.removeLast());
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want a constructor?

Comment: Can you provide a test case where those methods don't work?

Comment: (And why do you think the constructor has anything to do with your problem?)

Comment: You have a constructor in both classes, you use it yourself here `Link link = new Link();` compiler will generate it for you.

Comment: @user2357112 It's not necessarily that I don't want to use one, but that my professor would like us to know how to create a Linked List without the use of one. But I have exhausted all of my resources trying to figure this one out. I just can't. Maybe I've been looking at it for too long. And I don't think it has to do with my problem, but that I don't have anything I can use to compare my code to since I can't find any examples without that constructor there.

Comment: @GL007: you should clarify with your professor what he or she means.  Creating an instance of `LinkedList` is a lot different than making your own *implementation* of `LinkedList`.

Comment: @Łukasz so, I realize that and I was afraid I would be called out on it. I was having trouble wording my question, and thsat was the best I could do. I meant that no other code which I could find created 2 separate objects for the head and tail. It would usually just set one single object to null and call it good.

Comment: @PawełChorążyk yes, I can. I'll try to put it up.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to create linked list withou ever using a constructor for one. Implement it with using only static methods and static fields. Static context of a linked list will guarantee there will be no explicit constuctor calls. For whatever reason you would like to do such a thing.

Comment: "...my professor would like us to know how to create a Linked List without the use of one." - Aha.  You're taking one of those classes that should be titled "stupid Java tricks."

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the lack of a constructor. In the absence of an explicit constructor, Java makes one for you, and the effect is exactly the same as the constructor that you say you don't want.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I'm sorry. I guess I was maybe a little confused about what I was trying to ask. And I just couldn't find an example which entirely comparable, and I was already confused. I suppose the only thing that I needed to know all along, other than the fact that one of my tests were written incorrectly, is how to correctly write and pass my `addLast` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One change in your code is needed: you want the new link to point to your old head as "next" (not the other way round) because you want to insert it at the beginning.

```
public void addFirst(String aString) {
        Link link = new Link();
        link.setValue(aString);

        if (isEmpty()) {
            tail = link;
        } else {
            link.setNext(head);
        }
        head = link;
    }
```

Also, you need to change your tests as now you compare String to Link instances instead of String to String

```
    assertTrue("one".equals(list.removeFirst().getValue()));
    assertTrue("two".equals(list.removeFirst().getValue()));
    assertTrue("three".equals(list.removeFirst().getValue()));
```

After those changes the test passes for me (the first one, you didn't implement removeLast method for the second one).

Comment: Oh, Okay. That first part makes some sense, and I changed the test like you said and green light. However, I'm wondering wither or not there is a way to make it green light the way it was written? My professor was the one who wrote the test, but I thought he had said something along the lines that he had written one of them incorrectly. However, I'm not sure.

Comment: You can make them pass if your `list.removeFirst()` method will return `String` instead of `Link`. You should actually probably implement it this way as users of your `List` implementation shouldn't be aware of implementation details. `Link` class is an implementation detail and should be used only internally and not be visible externally (which can even be enforced by making it inner static class of List or making it package private in the same package as the List class). Also, you take `String` instance from user in `add` method, it would be consistent to return `String` in `removeFirst`.

Comment: I'm confused on how I would write this. Change it to a  String type, and have it return a string, but how? My brain feels so fried from the hours I've spent on this.

Comment: You just need to change the last line of `removeFirst` method from `return temp;` to  `return temp.getValue();` and change the method signature to return `String`. Nothing else needs to be changed I think.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense now that I think about it. Do you know what is going wrong as far as my `addLast` method goes? I thought that it would just be the inverse of my `addFirst` method, however the test does not greenlight.

Comment: It looks fine but you didn't show `removeLast` method used in test, maybe it's the same problem? ;-) Also, please accept the answer if it was correct.

Comment: Ah, it seems that I do not have a `removeLast` method as the test calls for. Would this mean that my `addLast` method is potential correct? And would `removeLast` be just the inverse of `removeFirst`? and I was going to accept it. ;)

Comment: `addLast` looks quite fine to me. `remove last` is not really a simple inverse of `removeFirst` as you have a single-linked list. You have the reference to the `tail` Link but you don't know what's before your `tail` Link. Therefore when you will want to remove your tail you will want to change the pointer of 'what is before tail' to `null` but you cannot find it in any other way than iterating over the list until you find it. You can find some examples in google, like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792682/delete-last-node-of-a-linked-list

Comment: Alright, I will take a look at it. Thank you so much for your help. I incredibly appreciate it, and you've been incredibly helpful!

Comment: @GL007 That's a pleasure to hear that :-) I hope you'll be able to make it work :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a constructor to assign `null`, `0` and `false` to object fields. Fields get these values automatically. Simply remove the constructor that only does such assignments and it will be no any difference in execution.

You can also assign other default values like `int a = 17` directly in declaration, and you can also include expressions like `int b = a + 1` assuming that the field `a` has been declared before. But you cannot pass parameters that must have different values for different instances. This is what the constructor is for.

You may still have other bugs remaining but it will be no constructor to blame.

Most often developers simply use the ready solution, [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: I am aware of this information. I think I was a little confused on what I was trying to ask. I'm just not sure where to go on this/ how to write and pass those two methods.

Comment: Why area you asking if you are aware?