# How do I delete a node at the end of a linked list without relying on methods?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have an assignment for my coding class that asks me to create a linked list without relying on the `SingleLinkedList` class or any of its methods. I am stuck on the last step which asks me to delete a node at the end of a linked list with only head and tail references and I believe I am not supposed to use the `removeLast` method.

I know I'm supposed to use list traversal with a while loop to identify the element before the last element but I am not sure how to go about it. Here is all of my code so far:

```
public class ListByHand {

private static class Node<E> {
    private E data;
    private Node<E> next;
    private E z;

    private Node(E dataItem) {
        data = z;
        next = null;
    }

    private Node(E dataItem, Node<E> nodeRef) {
        data = dataItem;
        next = nodeRef;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1. Created original list containing Bob, Floyd, Mary, and Sue
    Node<String> head = new Node<String>("Bob", null);
    Node<String> nodeRef = head;
    Node<String> tail = head;
    tail.next = new Node<String>("Floyd", null);
    tail = tail.next;
    tail.next = new Node<String>("Mary", null);
    tail = tail.next;
    tail.next = new Node<String>("Sue", null);
    tail = tail.next;

    // Loop to print each name in the node
    while(nodeRef != null) {
        System.out.println(nodeRef.data);
        nodeRef = nodeRef.next;
    }

    // 2. Added Mark to the front of the list
    head = new Node<String>("Mark", head);
    System.out.println(head.data);

    // 3. Deleted the first node in the list
    head = head.next;
    System.out.println(head.data);

    // 4. Added Peter to the end of the list
    tail.next = new Node<String>("Peter", null);
    tail = tail.next;
    System.out.println(tail.data);

    // 5. Deleted the last node in the list

}
}
```

Comment: You must have previous node and this may help you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792682/delete-last-node-of-a-linked-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nodeRef = head;
while (nodeRef.next != tail) nodeRef = nodeRef.next;
nodeRef.next = null;
tail = nodeRef;
```

Comment: It is indeed perfect thank you very much! And wow I actually tried that exact solution but i had != null instead of != tail lol

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
Node<String> node = head;
while (node.next != null && node.next.next != null) {
    node = node.next;
}
```

When the loop exits you should have the second to last node, right?

Comment: Actually, @stas answer is better.  Forgot about reference to tail.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, if you can, you should also include in your class the previous node.
From there you can easily take the tail of the linkedList and its previous element. If you cannot, see the second part of my answer.

You set the new tail to the previous element of the current tail and delete the current tail and here you go.

```
tail = tail->previous;
tail->next = null ;
```

However I would strongly advice creating methods to add and delete.

If you cannot use a double-linked list ( no previous element ) you need to iterate through your nodes one by one until your reach the last one (the tail). From there you can easily do what I suggested above
However I don't see the point of having your last element (of the list) as a variable since you cannot go backwards from there. But if that's your assignment anyway it looks like this

```
Node<String> tmp = head ;
while(tmp->next !=tail){
    tmp= tmp->next;
}
tail = tmp ;
tail->next = null ;
```

Comment: He mentions it has to be singly linked.

Comment: That's why you have my proposition without the doubly-link list.

Comment: @jgitter ok so OP said exactly this "to create a linked list without relying on the SingleLinkedList" meaning he cannot use the SingleLinkedList but he never said that he had to have a SingleLinkedList. With this doubt I decided to provide an answer for both cases just in case he was actually allowed to use doubly-linked list... I'm afraid I fail at seeing what is wrong with that

Comment: I'm guessing you don't take criticism well.  He implied it was a singly linked list, or the problem is trivial since he said the last node in the list was available.  Just... chill out.

Comment: I don't mind criticism at all. I just don't think your second comment was constructive at all. Yes the first part of my answer does not solve his problem I admit that. However, the doubt I had in the first place made me think that this case should also be covered in my answer. I simply tried my best to cover both cases just in case. And as I said in my previous comment I cannot see what is wrong with that. Worst case OP is not long to use it at all but I may be helpful for others who may stumble upon this post when googling for a similar issue. No offense taken on my part anyway ;-)